# Can i get confidence intervals using bootMer in lmer?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I have a glmm model built using glmmTMB:

```
M2 <- glmmTMB(TotalSG_18_beta ~ Sim_mean_CI + (1|Site) + (1|Transect), data = CI_simulations_18_beta_transformed, family=list(family="beta",link="logit"))
```

I have transformed my data and am using a beta distributed model as my data are not normal. 
I want to use bootMer from the lmer package to verify the adequacy of this model using bootstrapping. I'd like to split my dataset 80:20, so use 80% of the values to predict 20% and then compare with model output. However i can't seem to extract confidence intervals from the bootstrapped model.

I have tried the following code:

```
b_test_1 <- bootMer(M2,
                      FUN = function(x) confint(x),
                      nsim=10, 
                      use.u = TRUE, 
                      type = "parametric", 
                      .progress="txt")
```

And i see the following output:

```
Bootstrap Statistics :
             original       bias    std. error
t1*     -0.8895147064 -0.493229558   0.7950155
t2*     -0.8897969448 -0.493181702   0.7950244
t3*     -0.8953021883 -0.492248240   0.7951980
t4*     -0.8919079383 -0.492823765   0.7950909
t5*     -0.8954317661 -0.492226269   0.7952021
```

Here is the output from a summary:

```
summary(b_test_1)
          Length Class      Mode     
t0         15    -none-     numeric  
t         120    -none-     numeric  
R           1    -none-     numeric  
data        4    data.frame list     
seed      626    -none-     numeric  
statistic   1    -none-     function 
sim         1    -none-     character
call        7    -none-     call     
ran.gen     1    -none-     character
mle         2    -none-     list
```

I really do not understand the output. i was expecting to see my upper and lower CIs. I think i am going wrong on the line of FUN = function(x) but i can't seem to be able to find what i should be putting here. When i try the following function:

```
boot.ci(b_test_1, level = 0.95)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in boot.ci(b_test_1, length = 0.95) : 't' must of length 10
```

Can someone please help me understand what this output means and why i am getting this error? I'm new to R and coding so any help or advice is really appreciated